# Вывести общую сумму в представление

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Создал таблицу, и ни как не могу сложить общую сумму. Я новичок, и возможно, решаю задачу в корне не правильно. Не получается последний этап. Не считает переменную total.
Выводит ошибку:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'
```

Но если я заменю

```
 total = total +  @Convert.ToDouble((item.Price1 - item.Price5) * item.Price5)
```

на

```
 total = total +  @Convert.ToInt32((item.Price1 - item.Price5) * item.Price5)
```

то все считает нормально, но сбрасывает остаток. А мне этого не нужно. Как сделать, так чтобы сумма выводилась плавающим нулем?

Вот код:

```
   <table>
    .....
    .....
    </tr>
    @{
            var total = 0;

        }
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.R)
        { <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Price1
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Price3
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Price5
                </td>
                <td>
                    @((item.Price1 - item.Price3) * item.Price5)
                </td>
                </tr>
                 total = total +  @Convert.ToDouble((item.Price1 - item.Price5) * item.Price5)
    }
    </table>
<p>@total</p>
```

Comment: total и price все каких типов? И там где `total = total ...` возьмите в `@{}`

Comment: `public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price1 { get; set; }
        public int Price3 { get; set; }
        public decimal Price5 { get; set; }` Но при взятии скобки. Выводит ошибку.`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppepos\WebApplication45\WebApplication45\Views\Pr\Index.cshtml 70 
ression State
Error  Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code. WebApplication45 C:\Users\PC\source\r`

Comment: а `total`?............

Comment: var total /////

Comment: Вместо var подставил double и все заработало. Спасибо за помощь